# NSTimer not working well for UITableviewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, nstimer, reload, countdown

I have to create something like, there is UITableView which have much multiple rows with multiple sections and every row has different Timer showing in 'hh:mm:ss' format and it decrementing every second, just like countdown.

I'm getting problem that when i scroll UITableView, few UILabels re-initialised and countdown time gone and even it gets over-rides for few cells.
I'm using following code to achieve my requirement :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

       //Somewhere, in this method
       elapsedTimeTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(runningTimer:) userInfo:dic repeats:YES];

       [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:elapsedTimeTimer
                                         forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

-(void)runningTimer:(NSTimer *)timer {
       secondsLeft --; //I'm able to get seconds 

       hours = secondsLeft / 3600;
       minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
       seconds = (secondsLeft %3600) % 60;

       cell.lblTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
}
```

Please help me for solving this problem. Any kind of help, will surely appreciated.

Thanks.!!..

Comment: Create your data model separate from your view.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have an array of elements or dictionary to keep track of your timers.

Every cell in uitableview is reused and since your timers will be affected.

Instead of `elapsedTimeTimer`
I would use

```
elapsedTimeTimers[indexPath.row]
```

Where `elapsedTimeTimers` is array of timers.

Ofcourse, this applies if you have one section. If you have more then you will have to calculate correct index. Also, if you have an object to keep all this data, you could use objects id or something like that.

Comment: if instead of an array you create a NSDictionary[NSIndexPath] = NSTimer you don't have to worry about single or multiples sections

Comment: *NSMutableDictionary and yes, as I said in first sentance, you can do what one way or another, depending on your needs. NSMutableDictionary would be even better choice for checking if object already exists. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You must not create the timer object inside cellforRowatIndex. it will create too many timers objects as the datasource count. just create the timer once in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear or even after you set your datasource. I think your issue is you have scheduled more than one timer and all is fired.

Good Luck

Comment: I've taken one timer object and reloading table every second as per my condition with data manipulations. Let me check how it works exactly with different pagination and other condition.

Thanks for your suggestion .!!..